# Indoor-alternatives to kitchen stove

Tags: equipment, small-space, hop-utilization, boil-equipment

I am a kitchen-brewer doing 5 gls all-grain batches and am frustrated because the kitchen stove is lacking the last bit of power to yield a nice rolling boil. Are there any indoor-alternatives to the stove?

Comment: You should find a handful of good answers here: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/how-to-brew-all-grain-indoors.  Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Seconding the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem on our small apartment stove, and the best trick I could come up wih was to preheat water in a separate kettle while I'm doing other prep work so I can have hot water on hand rather than try to bring 3 gallons to a boil all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Electric brewing with heat sticks.  Or you can supplement your stove top with a little extra heating capacity using a heat stick.

Start here with this [heat stick page](http://www.3d0g.net/brewing/heatstick)
Listen to the April 29th 2010 Electric Brewing episode at [Basic Brewing Radio](http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=basic-brewing-radio-2010).

Comment: I've been using heatsticks for brew-in-a-bag AG for about 6 months now. I built two 1500W sticks (one with a right angle). I have to use two separate circuits, but I love the system. One mod I want to make to mine is adding a potentiometer to have a variable heat level. 2 sticks boils a bit violently with full volume - I'd love to have about 1.25-1.5x when I get up to boil. As a side note, I doubt I'll ever go to gas even when I have access to the great outdoors for brewing or move up to a larger batch size; electricity is too convenient!

Answer (score 1):

One thing I did in my apartment was to get a griddle that would cover 2 burners.  Put both burners on high, with the griddle on top.  Put the brew kettle on the middle of the griddle.  You get somewhere around 1.5 the BTUs of 1 burner (some is lost to waste heat, unless you rig up a proper way to hold that heat in, which I never really investigated).